# Angular 2: getting RouteParams from parent component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How do I get the RouteParams from a parent component?

`App.ts`:

```
@Component({
  ...
})

@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/', component: HomeComponent, as: 'Home'},
  {path: '/:username/...', component: ParentComponent, as: 'Parent'}
])

export class HomeComponent {
  ...
}
```

And then, in the `ParentComponent`, I can easily get my username param and set the child routes.

`Parent.ts`:

```
@Component({
  ...
})

@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/child-1', component: ChildOneComponent, as: 'ChildOne' },
  { path: '/child-2', component: ChildTwoComponent, as: 'ChildTwo' }
])

export class ParentComponent {

  public username: string;

  constructor(
    public params: RouteParams
  ) {
    this.username = params.get('username');
  }

  ...
}
```

But then, how can I get this same 'username' parameter in those child components? Doing the same trick as above, doesn't do it. Because those params are defined at the ProfileComponent or something??

```
@Component({
  ...
})

export class ChildOneComponent {

  public username: string;

  constructor(
    public params: RouteParams
  ) {
    this.username = params.get('username');
    // returns null
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: How about an input property on the children?  E.g., in the parent template: `<child-one-component [username]="username"> ...`

Comment: Would that also work on `<routerlink [username]="username">...`? And is that the way to go then @MarkRajcok?

Comment: I think you're asking if something like `<a [router-link]="[ './....', {username: username} ]` will work.  Sorry, I have no idea if that will work or not.  (I haven't played with routing much yet.)

Comment: I'm sorry @MarkRajcok , I typed it wrong.. I meant `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`, should I put an input on that. Because the child routes wil render there..

Comment: I forgot that ParentComponent is essentially a routing component, so there's no parent template that uses `<child-one-component>`, so there's no place to put the `[username]` binding.  Sorry, this was a bad/wrong suggestion on my part.

Comment: There might be useful information https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6204#issuecomment-173273143

Comment: As pointed out by @Lordking ng2 does not handle deeply nested routes. Now, going with the solution wherein one requests the parent (precisely the 2nd ancestor) injector, and getting the RouteParams from there seems to be an ugly but nevertheless a temporary workaround for the problem in hand. Shall update this post once a better solution is constructed for deeply nested parent child relationships.

Comment: For people interested in more than just parent's, but want all ancestors' params, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42301718/4185989

Comment: Starting from Angular 5 you can access parent params via paramsInheritanceStrategy No need to subscribe to parent route. See https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions

Answer (score 74, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Now that Angular2 final was officially released, the correct way to do this is the following:

```
export class ChildComponent {

    private sub: any;

    private parentRouteId: number;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.sub = this.route.parent.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.parentRouteId = +params["id"];
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

---

**ORIGINAL:**

Here is how i did it using the "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.6" package:

```
export class ChildComponent {

    private sub: any;

    private parentRouteId: number;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.sub = this.router.routerState.parent(this.route).params.subscribe(params => {
            this.parentRouteId = +params["id"];
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

In this example the route has the following format: /parent/:id/child/:childid

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    {
        path: '/parent/:id',
        component: ParentComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '/child/:childid', component: ChildComponent }]
    }
];
```

Comment: You need to call this in **ngOnInit** (as shown) not in the constructor as I foolishly tried to do at first.

Comment: There's an alternative way since Angular 5.2 that doesn't require you to traverse `parent` 1+ times. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48511516/4185989 Still worth considering the `subscribe` / `unsubscribe` pattern from this answer, though.

Comment: In Angular 6 `this.activatedRoute.parent.snapshot.params.someParam`

Comment: Solution pointed to by @jmq is the best for angular 6 as well, we do not need to subscribe separately for parent id.

Comment: Perfect solution! Buy why I need to subscribe to get the parent params? The param is there already! ::thinking::

Comment: what is the difference b/w this.route.parent.paramMap and this.route.parent.params? It happens that if changing params with paramMap the solution stops to work, any help?

Answer (score 10):

You shouldn't try to use `RouteParams` in your `ChildOneComponent`.

Use [`RouteRegistry`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/RouteRegistry-class.html), instead!

```
@Component({
  ...
})

export class ChildOneComponent {

  public username: string;

  constructor(registry: RouteRegistry, location: Location) {
    route_registry.recognize(location.path(), []).then((instruction) => {
      console.log(instruction.component.params['username']);
    })
  }


  ...
}
```

**UPDATE:** As from this pull request (angular beta.9): https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7163

You can now access to the current instruction without `recognize(location.path(), [])`.

Example:

```
@Component({
  ...
})

export class ChildOneComponent {

  public username: string;

  constructor(_router: Router) {
    let instruction = _router.currentInstruction();
    this.username = instruction.component.params['username'];
  }

  ...
}
```

**I haven't tried it, yet**

Further details here:

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta9-2016-03-09
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/Router-class.html

**UPDATE 2:**
A small change as from angular 2.0.0.beta15:

Now `currentInstruction` is not a function anymore. Moreover, you have to load the `root` router. (thanks to @Lxrd-AJ for reporting)

```
@Component({
  ...
})

export class ChildOneComponent {

  public username: string;

  constructor(_router: Router) {
    let instruction = _router.root.currentInstruction;
    this.username = instruction.component.params['username'];
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Is this the way it is supposed to be done for child routes? I'm also running into this issue where child routes cannot see routeparams of parent components. 

For example the route /users/:user_id/posts/:post_id, I cannot get the user_id from the posts component.... 

It seems hacky to me to have to use RouteRegistry.

Comment: @mharris7190 I updated my answer. Starting from angular beta.9 you can get the current instruction directly from the Router component.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm about to upgrade from beta.6 to beta.13 so I'll try it out after I do.

Comment: A slight edit to this answer, Use `_router.root.currentInstruction.component.params['id']` . Emphasis on **root** as you now get the currentInstruction from the root router and not `_router`.   
PS: I am using `angular2.0.0-beta.15`

Comment: _router.root doesn't exist anymore. (I use Angular 2.4.7)

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned by Günter Zöchbauer, I used the comment at https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6204#issuecomment-173273143 to address my problem. I used the `Injector` class from `angular2/core` to fetch the routeparams of the parent. Turns out angular 2 does not handle deeply nested routes. Maybe they'll add that in the future.

```
constructor(private _issueService: IssueService,
            private _injector: Injector) {}

getIssues() {
    let id = this._injector.parent.parent.get(RouteParams).get('id');
    this._issueService.getIssues(id).then(issues => this.issues = issues);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work anymore on the angular2 RC router.

Answer (score 6):

I found an ugly but working solution, by requesting the parent (precisely the 2nd ancestor) injector, and by getting the `RouteParams` from here.

Something like

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class ChildOneComponent {
  public username: string;

  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    let params = injector.parent.parent.get(RouteParams);

    this.username = params.get('username');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for sharing this, is there any bugtracker entry or statement by the angular team on how this will be handled in the future?

Comment: Seems that .parent has been removed on RC3

Answer (score 4):

**RC5 + @angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1 SOLUTION:** It seems that `this.router.routerState.queryParams` has been deprecated. You can get the parent route params this way:

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
}    

this.activatedRoute.parent.params.subscribe(
  (param: any) => {
    let userId = param['userId'];
    console.log(userId);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take component of parent route inside of child component from injector and then get any from child component. In you case like this

```
@Component({
  ...
})

export class ChildOneComponent {

  public username: string;

  constructor(
    public params: RouteParams
    private _injector: Injector

  ) {
    var parentComponent = this._injector.get(ParentComponent)

    this.username = parentComponent.username;
    //or
    this.username = parentComponent.params.get('username');
  }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Passing Injector instance to constructor in child component may not be good if you want to write unit tests for your code.

The easiest way to work around this is to have a service class in the parent component, in which you save your required params.

```
@Component({
    template: `<div><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>`,
    directives: [RouterOutlet],
    providers: [SomeServiceClass]
})
@RouteConfig([
    {path: "/", name: "IssueList", component: IssueListComponent, useAsDefault: true}
])
class IssueMountComponent {
    constructor(routeParams: RouteParams, someService: SomeServiceClass) {
        someService.id = routeParams.get('id');
    }
}
```

Then you just inject the same service to child components and access the params.

```
@Component({
    template: `some template here`
})
class IssueListComponent implements OnInit {
    issues: Issue[];
    constructor(private someService: SomeServiceClass) {}

    getIssues() {
        let id = this.someService.id;
        // do your magic here
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getIssues();
    }
}
```

Note that you should scope such service to your parent component and its child components using "providers" in parent component decorator.

I recommend this article about DI and scopes in Angular 2: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/08/20/host-and-visibility-in-angular-2-dependency-injection.html

Answer (score 2):

**In RC6, router 3.0.0-rc.2** (probably works in RC5 as well), you can take route params from the URL as a snapshot in case that params won't change, without observables with this one liner:

`this.route.snapshot.parent.params['username'];`

Don't forget to inject ActivatedRoute as follows:

`constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {};`

Answer (score 2):

With RxJS's `Observable.combineLatest`, we can get something close to the idiomatic params handling:

```ts
import 'rxjs/add/operator/combineLatest';

import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({ /* ... */ })
export class SomeChildComponent {
  email: string;
  id: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    Observable.combineLatest(this.route.params, this.route.parent.params)
        .forEach((params: Params[]) => {
          this.id = params[0]['id'];
          this.email = params[1]['email'];
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing this kind of hack for Angular 2 rc.1

```ts
import { Router } from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

interface ParameterObject {
  [key: string]: any[];
};

/**
 * Traverse route.parent links until root router and check each level
 * currentInstruction and group parameters to single object.
 *
 * e.g.
 * {
 *   id: [314, 593],
 *   otherParam: [9]
 * }
 */
export default function mergeRouteParams(router: Router): ParameterObject {
  let mergedParameters: ParameterObject = {};
  while (router) {
    let currentInstruction = router.currentInstruction;
    if (currentInstruction) {
      let currentParams = currentInstruction.component.params;
      _.each(currentParams, (value, key) => {
        let valuesForKey = mergedParameters[key] || [];
        valuesForKey.unshift(value);
        mergedParameters[key] = valuesForKey;
      });
    }
    router = router.parent;
  }
  return mergedParameters;
}
```

Now in view I collect parameters in view instead of reading `RouteParams` I just get them through router:

```ts
@Component({
  ...
})

export class ChildishComponent {

  constructor(router: Router) {
    let allParams = mergeRouteParams(router);
    let parentRouteId = allParams['id'][0];
    let childRouteId = allParams['id'][1];
    let otherRandomParam = allParams.otherRandomParam[0];
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Works great! I ended up making this method private inside of a `MergedRouteParams` class that implements the `get` method of the standard `RouteParams` class (second parameter is index, defaults to zero).

Answer (score 0):

In **FINAL** with little help of **RXJS** you can combine both maps (from child and parent):

```
(route) => Observable
    .zip(route.params, route.parent.params)
    .map(data => Object.assign({}, data[0], data[1]))
```

Other questions one might have:

- Is it really a good idea to use above - because of coupling (couple child component with parent's param's - not on api level - hidden coupling),
- Is it proper approach in term of RXJS (it would require hardcore RXJS user feedback ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on the snapshot with the following, but if it changes, your `id` property will not be updated.

This example also shows how you can subscribe to all ancestor parameter changes and look for the one you are interested in by merging all of the parameter observables.  However, be careful with this method because there could be multiple ancestors that have the same parameter key/name.

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';

// This traverses the route, following ancestors, looking for the parameter.
function getParam(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, key: string): any {
  if (route != null) {
    let param = route.params[key];
    if (param === undefined) {
      return getParam(route.parent, key);
    } else {
      return param;
    }
  } else {
    return undefined;
  }
}

@Component({ /* ... */ })
export class SomeChildComponent {

  id: string;

  private _parameterSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // There is no need to do this if you subscribe to parameter changes like below.
    this.id = getParam(this.route.snapshot, 'id');

    let paramObservables: Observable<Params>[] =
      this.route.pathFromRoot.map(route => route.params);

    this._parametersSubscription =
      Observable.merge(...paramObservables).subscribe((params: Params) => {
        if ('id' in params) {
          // If there are ancestor routes that have used
          // the same parameter name, they will conflict!
          this.id = params['id'];
        }
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._parameterSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Getting RouteParams from parent component in Angular 8 -**

I have a route http://localhost:4200/partner/student-profile/1234/info

*Parent route* - student-profile

*Param* - 1234 (student_id)

*Child route* - info

**Accessing param in child route (info) -**

**Import**

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
```

**Constructor**

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }
```

**Accessing parent route params**

```
this.activatedRoute.parent.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => this.studentId = (params.get('student_id')));
```

Now, our variable ***studentId*** has the param value.