# How to get all route params/data

Tags: angular, angular-router

Given a route config

```
{
   path: '/root/:rootId',
   children: [{
       path: '/child1/:child1Id',
       children: [{
           path: '/child2/:child2Id
           component: TestComponent
       }]
   }]
}
```

In TestComponent how can I easily get all route params. I'm wondering if there is an easier way than

```
let rootId = route.parent.parent.snapshot.params;
let child1Id = route.parent.snapshot.params;
let child2Id = route.snapshot.params;
```

This seems overly redundant especially if I'm watching the route params observable instead of access the param through the route snapshot. This method also seems fragile since it would break If I moved any any of the routes/params around. Im used to angular ui-router where a single object $stateParams was supplied with all param data easily accessible. I have these same concerns with route resolved data along being accessed from a single node in the route tree. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 76):

As of Angular 5.2, you can do Router configuration to inherit all params to child states. See [this commit](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/5efea2f) if interested in the gory details, but here's how it's working for me:

Wherever you have your call to `RouterModule.forRoot()`, include a configuration object with the inheritance strategy set to `always` (default is `emptyOnly`):

```typescript
import {RouterModule, ExtraOptions} from "@angular/router";

export const routingConfiguration: ExtraOptions = {
  paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always'
};

export const Routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, routingConfiguration);
```

Now when you're in a child component looking at a `ActivatedRoute`, ancestors' params appear there (e.g. `activatedRoute.params`) rather than something messy like `activatedRoute.parent.parent.parent.params`. You could access the value directly (e.g. `activatedRoute.params.value.userId`) or subscribe via `activatedRoute.params.subscribe(...)`.

Comment: You still need to subscribe to `activatedRoute.params.subscribe(...)`, but very helpful!

Comment: Unforfunately this still does not address the issue of being able to access all child route params from the top route, this only works in the inverse. I want to be at the top route and get all children params, even 3 or 4 levels down, and an empty string/undefined if none exists. Gunter's answer should work for this.

Comment: @Lansana Indeed, this doesn't accomplish that. I first used Gunter's solution, and it works well for many situations, but I think I had trouble in a resolver with the data not being available, IIRC. It's worth a shot seeing if it suits your needs, though.

Comment: In case you can use ActivatedRouteSnapshot, it's simple and just a matter of calling `activatedRouteSnapshot.parent.params`

Comment: @Lansana I don't follow. What do you mean accessing from top? Every route is bind to component. If some component has children, then again, those children have own routes and it is logical, that parent should not be able to access params of child, even though parent will be rendered as well.

Comment: @Eugene This was my use case if I remember correctly: Had a sidebar that had sub-menus (similar to ProductHunt's old sidebar if you remember that). The top level sidebar links were `/cat`. The submenu links were something like `/cat/:subcat/bar`. But the parent was never navigated away from when a child was activated, that is why I needed to know which unique child route param was activated so I could use that state to manage my template in the parent component. Ended up having to use a service to track the state of child routes in my parent. Does it make more sense?

Comment: Okay. You just described my case. I guess it is both okay and at the same time not so much. I also use service, to `.subscribe` in parent and then `.next` in a child component, to let parent know, what is active atm, so that parent could react accordingly. But at the same time allowing parent to have access to parameters, that are specific to child route would be also incorrect IMO. To be fair this service communication approach was widely used in AngularJS as well. Maybe it is a pattern.

Answer (score 8):

You need to iterate the route segments.

Something like

```ts
var params = [];
var route = router.routerState.snapshot.root;
do {
 params.push(route.params); 
 route = route.firstChild;
} while(route);
```

This gives you the list of `params` of each route segment, you then can read the param values from them that you want.

`Object.keys(params)` might work to get all available param names from a `param` instance.

Comment: I think there are some typos: `params.add` -> `params.push` and `route.firstChild()` -> `route.firstChild`.

Comment: Put a variant of this into a service: https://gist.github.com/jessemorton/3ea95bce1caae0234235f72530cbb45e

Answer (score 2):

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

data$ = of(this.route).pipe(
    expand(route => of(route['parent'])),
    takeWhile(route => !!route['parent']),
    pluck('snapshot', 'data'),
    reduce(merge));
```

**Explanation:**

Calling expand here creates an observable for each route in the parent chain. Takewhile is used so that it stops recursing when route['parent'] returns null, or at the root route.

Then, for all of those routes in the observable, pluck will map each to it's 'snapshot.data' property.

Finally, reduce is being fed the merge function from lodash to combine all the data objects into one object. This stream aggregates all the data from the current route through the parent routes

Comment: @Allan Sure. Calling expand here creates an observable for each route in the parent chain. Takewhile is used so that it stops recursing when route['parent'] returns null, or at the root route. Then, for all of those routes in the observable, pluck will map each to it's 'snapshot.data' property. Finally, reduce is being fed the merge function from lodash to combine all the data objects into one object. This stream aggregates all the data from the current route through the parent routes

Comment: so as "reduce((acc, val) => ({ ...acc, ...val }))"

Comment: holy love of god. Does it strike anyone else that this is an utterly ridiculous amount of work just to get the damned url parameters?

Answer (score 2):

#### Route params from all active Outlets

If you have a use case where you need to know params from the `primary outlet` in a component routed in a `secondary outlet`, this function collects **all** params from **all** active outlets recursively:

```
const getParams = (route) => ({
  ...route.params,
  ...route.children.reduce((acc, child) =>
    ({ ...getParams(child), ...acc }), {}) 
});

getParams(router.routerState.snapshot.root);
```

If the current URL is `/path/to/42(outlet:path/to/99)`, the resulting object could be:

```
{ primaryParam: '42', outletParam: '99' }
```

The keys in the object depend on your route configuration in Angular.

Answer (score 1):

Angular 5:

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/observable/combineLatest';



 constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    combineLatest(
      this.activatedRoute.data,
      this.activatedRoute.params
    ).subscribe(([{from}, params]) => {
      this.params.from = from;
      this.params.id = params['id'];
      this.loadData();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Get all activated route snapshot param under lazy load modules
 * @see RouterModule.forChild(routes)
 */
public static getSnapshotParams(route: ActivatedRoute): { [key: string]: string } {
    const params: { [key: string]: string } = {};
    do {
        const param = route.snapshot.params;
        for (let key in param) {
            params[key] = param[key];
        }
        route = route.parent;
    } while (route);
    return params;
}

/**
 * Get all activated route stream observable param under lazy load modules
 * @see RouterModule.forChild(routes)
 * @see Observable
 * @see Params
 */
public static getRouteParam(route: ActivatedRoute, routeKey: string): Observable<number> {
    const obs: Observable<Params>[] = [];
    do {
        obs.push(route.params);
        route = route.parent;
    } while (route);
    return merge(...obs).pipe(
        filter(param => !!param[routeKey]),
        map(param => param[routeKey])
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Based on another answers to this question, I ended up with this:

```
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router'

export function extractAllRouteParams(router: Router): any {
  const params: any = {}
  let route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot | null = router.routerState.snapshot.root
  do {
    Object.keys(route.params).forEach(
      (key) => (params[key] = route?.params[key])
    )
    route = route.firstChild
  } while (route)
  return params
}
```

Put it into an shared .ts file, so you can use it anywhere, passing an instance of the router to the function, for example:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  const { groupId, sectionId } = extractAllRouteParams(this.router)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created the following service to be able to get all route params as a [ParamMap](https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap). The main idea behind it, is to recursively parse all the parameters from the child routes.

[Github gist](https://gist.github.com/m-spyratos/5fa0deedc173458d673df7e4c82f3e49)

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {
  ActivatedRoute,
  Router,
  NavigationEnd,
  ParamMap,
  PRIMARY_OUTLET,
  RouterEvent
} from '@angular/router';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ParamMapService {

  paramMap: Observable<ParamMap>;

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.paramMap = this.getParamMapObservable();
  }

  private getParamMap(route: ActivatedRoute): ParamMap {
    const map: Map<string, string | string[]> = new Map();

    while (route) {
      route.snapshot.paramMap.keys.forEach((key) => {
        map.set(key, this.getParamMapValue(route.snapshot.paramMap, key));
      });
      route = route.firstChild;
    }

    return <ParamMap>{
      keys: this.getParamMapKeys(map),
      has: this.getParamMapMethodHas(map),
      get: this.getParamMapMethodGet(map),
      getAll: this.getParamMapMethodGetAll(map)
    };
  }

  private getParamMapMethodGet(map: Map<string, string | string[]>): (name: string) => string | null {
    return (name: string): string | null => {
      const value = map.get(name);
      if (typeof value === 'string') {
        return value;
      }
      if (Array.isArray(value) && value.length) {
        return value[0];
      }
      return null;
    };
  }

  private getParamMapMethodGetAll(map: Map<string, string | string[]>): (name: string) => string[] {
    return (name: string): string[] => {
      const value = map.get(name);
      if (typeof value === 'string') {
        return [value];
      }
      if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        return value;
      }
      return [];
    };
  }

  private getParamMapMethodHas(map: Map<string, string | string[]>): (name: string) => boolean {
    return (name: string): boolean => map.has(name);
  }

  private getParamMapKeys(map: Map<string, string | string[]>): string[] {
    return Array.from(map.keys());
  }

  private getParamMapObservable(): Observable<ParamMap> {
    return this.router.events
      .filter((event: RouterEvent) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .map(() => this.route)
      .filter((route: ActivatedRoute) => route.outlet === PRIMARY_OUTLET)
      .map((route: ActivatedRoute) => this.getParamMap(route));
  }

  private getParamMapValue(paramMap: ParamMap, key: string): string | string[] {
    return (paramMap.getAll(key).length > 1 ? paramMap.getAll(key) : paramMap.get(key));
  }
}
```

---

**Example Usage**

```
id;

constructor(private paramMapService: ParamMapService) {
  this.paramMapService.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
    this.id = paramMap.get('id');
  });
}
```

**Note**

ES6 [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is being used in the service. To support older browsers, do one of the following:

- Uncomment the `import 'core-js/es6/map';` line in `polyfills.ts`, **or**
- Convert all Map occurrences to a simple object.

Answer (score -1):

I got the first route param this way:

`console.log(this.route.snapshot.firstChild.params)`

Comment: This will not work everywhere. This would be in very specific scenarios when route object is already handled.