# Angular : Get value of parameter in parent route

Tags: angular, angular-activatedroute

I am having URLs like

- `www.yoursite.com/accounts/:accountid/info`
- `www.yoursite.com/accounts/:accountid/users` etc.

An integer value `accountid` is available in the URL

But can't access it using the `ActivatedRoute` parameters.

Now I am splitting the URL to get the `accountid`

Is there a better way to access the value other than splitting the URL ?

**Update**

I have a different module called `account` which includes all components and services for account related pages.

I am lazy loading this module. So in the root level routing , that is `app-routing` I specify

```
{ path:'account', loadChildren : './account/account.module#AccountModule' }
```

In the account module's `account-routing`, I specify the children by

```
path: 'account/:accountid', component: AccountComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'info', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'info', component: InfoComponent },
      { path: 'users, component: UsersComponent }
      {path: '**', redirectTo: 'info'}
    ]
```

**Note :**

We can access the params in children path if  present. But not of parent part why?

I am getting `undefined` for params in parent path

Comment: instead of use `observable` approach you can use  route `snapshot` method

Answer (score 95):

With the help of this **[article](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-parent-routing-params)**, the problem was solved.

For accessing the `params` in parent route, we need to use `activeRoute.parent.params`
instead of `activeRoute.params`

```
this.activatedRoute.parent.params.subscribe(
    (params) => 
    { 
                 console.log(params.accountid); 
     });
```

Also from [**this stackoverflow question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42300642/how-to-get-all-route-params-data?noredirect=1&lq=1) , a solution to make all params (including parent route params) available to child routes was found.

This is done by including a configuration object with the `paramsInheritanceStrategy` set to `always` where we import `RouterModule`

eg :

```
import {RouterModule, ExtraOptions} from "@angular/router";

export const routingConfiguration: ExtraOptions = {
  paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always'
};

export const Routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, routingConfiguration);
```

Now we can access both parent and child route params using  `activeRoute.params`

Answer (score 19):

All you need is to use `paramsInheritanceStrategy`. See https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions

Comment: Work well for me on Angular 14.

Comment: This should be the right answer. Still working perfectly on Angular 15.

Answer (score 8):

Try this solution:

```
 this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
        const accountid= params['accountid'];
    });
```

You can also try this if above didn't work. ([Got this solution from here](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-parent-routing-params))

```
this.router.parent.params.switchMap(params => {
  // params = { id: 1234 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have already tried this. Not working this case. I have updated the question to include more details.

Comment: @Seba Cherian here ,accountid is 'route param' not 'query param'  so i think your solution won't work to get accountid value.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem consider marking this answer/answer that worked as accepted(tick the answer)

Comment: Starting from Angular 5 you can use paramsInheritanceStrategy instead. No need to subscribe to parent route.

Answer (score 4):

The `parent` property has been added to the route now:

```
 this.route.parent.paramMap
                .subscribe(params => {
                    if (params.has('accountid')) {
                        this.'accountid'= params.get('accountid');
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

private route: ActivatedRoute

this.route.snapshot.parent.params['accountid'])

Answer (score 1):

I need to get params all the way from `app-routing` so this worked for me

```
this.route.firstChild?.params.subscribe((param) => {
      const accountId = param['account-id'];
});
```

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

create the object of ActivatedRoute in constructor

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

so once object get created you will get route parameters like

```
    let accountid = this.route.snapshot.params['accountid'];

    console.log(accountid);
```

OR

```
let accountid = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('accountid');
console.log(accountid);
```

I hope this will be useful.

Comment: This doesn't work if you're trying to get the param from a parent route as the OP is requesting

Answer (score 0):

if you're doing a standalone main.ts without app.modules, you can use the `withRouterConfig`

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    // https://this-is-angular.github.io/angular-guides/docs/standalone-apis/configuring-the-router-using-standalone-features
    provideRouter(routes,
      withRouterConfig({paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always'})
    ),
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

for my case I had to go up several parents

```
this._activatedRoute.parent.parent.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to access the current route params through following code in your constructor,

```
this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
     if(params['accountid']) {
         console.log(params['accountid'])  // use it where you need
     }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have already tried this. Not working this case. I have updated the question to include more details.

Comment: @jophab show the actual code where you are using this!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I tried this code in ngOnInit() of the InfoComponent. For the accountid, I am getting undefined. When I tried adding a param to child route and used the same code to log the param, it works. But it doesnot work with params of parent path

Comment: @jophab Can you provide Stackblitz?

Comment: This doesn't work if you're trying to get the param from the parent route.