# How do you get params from multiple outlets?

Tags: angular

I have the following URL

```
http://localhost:3000/#/(settings/subscriptions/2/manage-subscriptions//modal:root/products/15/edit)
```

I want to get **2** and **15**. I have used `route.params` from `ActivatedRoute` but it only returns 15. Not both. I have tried using `route.parent.parent.parent.params` but I only get an empty `{}`.

These two params are from two different outlets. Surely Angular has a way for you to get access to params from other outlets. But I haven't found any answers. I've searched the whole `route` tree but didn't find anything.

And I use different names for the **ids**. One is called `/:subscriptionId` and the other `/:productId`. Any help is appreciated.

Here is how the routing looks:

```
{
    path: '',
    component: SettingsComponent,
    canDeactivate: [ModalGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'subscriptions/:subscriptionId/manage-subscriptions',
        component: ManageSubscriptions,
      },
    ],
},
```

The modal:

```
{
    path: 'root',
    outlet: 'modal',
    component: ModalComponent,
    canDeactivate: [ModalGuard],
    children: [
        {
          path: 'products',
          children: [
            {
               path: ':id/edit',
               component: EditProduct,
            },
          ]
        }
    ],
}
```

Comment: You can get the url and by parsing the string get the values... but it's a bit ugly. how does the routing implemented?

Comment: @noamsteiner Yes, I've thought about doing that. But Angular must have thought of this. 
Added routing to the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. Huge thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66931332/12382500

```
const getParams = (route) => ({
  ...route.params,
  ...route.children.reduce((acc, child) =>
    ({ ...getParams(child), ...acc }), {})
});
```

And you use it like this:

```
getParams(this.router.routerState.snapshot.root)
```

Remember that this is `Router`. Not `ActivatedRoute`.

Comment: Very useful. I used this in conjunction with NavigationEnd to access all the route params whenever a route changes.

`this.router.events.pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)).subscribe(_ => this.routeParams = getParams(this.router.routerState.snapshot.root));`