# How to get route param from parent

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I basically need a translation of [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34500147/angular-2-getting-routeparams-from-parent-component) but for AngularDart (I am on Angular 4 but an answer in 5 would be fine of course). I see `subscribe` in  the router if I inject it but no success getting parent parameters from that.

Comment: What version of angular and angular_router (if any) are you using?

Comment: @LeonSenft currently on Angular 4.0.0+2 and angular_router 1.0.2, but if anything is changed or makes sense to only answer this in 5 (which I think is latest) that is fine by me!

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to answer this for angular_router version 1. For version 2 (which is compatible with angular 5+), the router state object you're given on route activation contains all of the parameters for that route and any parent routes: https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/angular_router/2.0.0-alpha+14/angular_router/OnActivate/onActivate.html

Comment: Well that sounds useful @LeonSenft let me just try a version upgrade! thanks!